# Notation of expectation for two subset

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

I have two set of empirical samples $X_1 \in \mathbb{R}$, $X_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $X_1 \cap X_2 = \emptyset$, and a function $f:\mathbb{R} \xrightarrow{} \mathbb{R}$. Let $n(X_1) = n_1$ and $n(X_2) = n_2$, then I want to claim that
$$ \frac{1}{n_1}\sum_{i\in X_1} f(x_i) - \frac{1}{n_2}\sum_{i\in X_2} f(x_i) \approx \mathbb{E}_x[f(x_1) ] - \mathbb{E}_x[f(x_2) ] = \mathbb{E}_x[f(x_1) -f(x_2)].$$
But I'm confused the subscript $\mathbb{E}$.

One of my colleague insists that I'm not be able to merge them because
$$ \frac{1}{n_1}\sum_{i\in X_1} f(x_i) - \frac{1}{n_2}\sum_{i\in X_2} f(x_i) \approx \mathbb{E}_{x_1}[f(x_1) ] - \mathbb{E}_{x_2}[f(x_2) ]  $$
I thought that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are just different set in the same space, so I could write $\mathbb{E}_x$ rather than $\mathbb{E}_{x_1}$ or $\mathbb{E}_{x_2}$ so that I can merge them into a single expectation. Which is the correct notation?

Answer (score 1):

The expectation operator $\mathbb{E}$ does not need a subscript. But I think there may be some underlying confusion here, arising from the difference between an *empirical sample* and a *random variable*. A random variable $X$ is an abstract entity. An empirical sample is a set of observations $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_N\}$ generated according to the (perhaps unobserved) underlying structure of $X$. The expectation operator $\mathbb{E}$ operates on random variables, not on empirical samples.

$\mathbb{E}$ is a linear operator. This means that $\mathbb{E}[X_1 - X_2]$ = $\mathbb{E}[X_1] - \mathbb{E}[X_2]$. Applying the expectation operator to a real-valued random variable $X$ maps it to some value in $\mathbb{R}$, which is its mean. It does not matter if $X_1$ and $X_2$ represent completely different things: $X_1$ could be the roll on a 6-sided die, and $X_2$ could be the average test score of a class of students.

Applying a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to a random variable $X$ defines a new random variable, $f(X)$. You could give this new random variable its own name, and say $Y=f(X)$. By the same logic as earlier, $\mathbb{E}[Y_1 - Y_2]$ = $\mathbb{E}[Y_1] - \mathbb{E}[Y_2]$ for any two random variables $Y_1$ and $Y_2$. Therefore, if $Y_1=f(X_1)$ and $Y_2=f(X_2)$, then this implies $\mathbb{E}[f(X_1) - f(X_2)]$ = $\mathbb{E}[f(X_1)] - \mathbb{E}[f(X_2)]$. (As an aside: it's worth noting however that this is *not* the same thing as $f(\mathbb{E}[X_1]) - f(\mathbb{E}[X_2])$, in general!)